# Why my custom submit handler isn't working in menu item edit form?

Tags: forms, 8

Code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymod_form_menu_link_content_menu_link_content_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymod_menu_link_content_form_submit');
}

function mymod_menu_link_content_form_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $formState) {
  //some code
}
```

Debug shows me that my custom submit handler is added to `$form['#submit']` array as a first item. However this submit handler is never called.

Comment: Do you clean caches ? and do you run your page with a "die()" in the "mymod_menu_link_content_form_submit" function ?

Comment: I've cleared cache multiple times. It seems that only code in alter hook implementation is running upon submit.

Comment: Is the function located at the same file?

Comment: unfortunately yes it is :( no idea what have done wrong

Answer (score 3):

Forms can have submit callbacks in two places. Either on the form level or on the button that is pressed. The form level callbacks are only invoked if no button-specific callbacks are specified.

Entity forms generally have the submit callbacks on the submit button, which is usually `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']`.

This was the same in Drupal 7, although the node form and possibly others had a backwards compatibility layer that also invoked form-level submit callbacks, but this was removed.